# What is the "base class" for numeric value types?

Tags: c#, .net, types

Say I want to have a method that takes any kind of number, is there a base class (or some other concept) that I can use?

As far as I know I have to make overloads for all the different numeric types (`Int32`, `Int16`, `Byte`, `UInt32`, `Double`, `Float`, `Decimal`, etc). This seems awfully tedious. Either that or use the type `object` and throw exceptions if they are not convertible or assignable to a `double` - which is pretty bad as it means no compile time checking.

**UPDATE:**
OK thanks for the comments, you are right Scarecrow and Marc, in fact declaring it as `Double` actually works for all except `Decimal`.

So the answer I was looking for is `Double` - it acts like a base class here since most numeric types are assignable to it. (I guess `Decimal` is not assignable to `Double`, as it could get too big.)

```
public void TestFormatDollars() {
    int i = 5;
    string str = FormatDollars(i);   // this is OK
    byte b = 5;
    str = FormatDollars(b);     // this is OK
    decimal d = 5;
    str = FormatDollars(d);     // this does not compile - decimal is not assignable to double
}

public static string FormatDollars(double num) {
    return "$" + num;
}
```

Comment: What numeric types aren't assignable to double? (Except for the big number classes that support arbitrarily large numbers)

Comment: @scarecrow - decimal is 96 bit... a lot of others simply aren't good matches for the range/scale.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you want to do with the numbers inside the method?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The answer is: you don't need to provide overloads for ALL the numeric types, just for **Double** and **Decimal**. All others (except maybe some very unusually large ones) will be automatically converted to these.

Not a *base class* but in fact that was the red herring. The base class System.ValueType doesn't help much as it includes types that are not numerics. The language reference i was reading was what got me confused in the first place :)

(I was just looking for who to attribute the answer to and it was a combination of Scarecrow and Marc Gravell, but since they were comments i have put the answer here)

Comment: Actually, this gives ambiguous method signatures. Overloading one of them does the trick.

Answer (score 15):

There isn't one (or at least, not one that *just* means "numbers"). You could use:

```
void Foo<T>(T value) where T : struct {...}
```

But that allows *any* struct - not just numbers. If you want to do arithmetic, [generic operators](https://web.archive.org/web/20090225170037/https://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) may be of use. Other than that; overloads it the most viable option.

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 12):

What I do:

```
 public interface INumeric<T>
 {
     T Zero { get; }
     T One { get; }
     T MaxValue { get; }
     T MinValue { get; }
     T Add(T a, T b);
     // T Substract(....
     // T Mult...
 }  

 public struct Numeric: 
     INumeric<int>, 
     INumeric<float>,
     INumeric<byte>,
     INumeric<decimal>,
     // INumeric<other types>
 {
     int INumeric<int>.Zero => 0;
     int INumeric<int>.One => 1;
     int INumeric<int>.MinValue => int.MinValue;
     int INumeric<int>.MaxValue => int.MaxValue;
     int INumeric<int>.Add(int x, int y) => x + y;

     // other implementations...
 }
```

Now, you can use it in a method:

```
bool IsZero<TNum, T>(TNum ops, T number) 
   where TNum : INumeric<T>
{
   return number == ops.Zero;      
}
```

or extension method

```
 public static bool IsZero<TNum, T>(this TNum ops, T number)
      where TNum : INumeric<T>
 {
      return number == ops.Zero;
 }
```

and in your code:

```
 ...
 var n = new Numeric(); // can be an static prop

 Console.WriteLine(IsZero(n, 5)); // false
 Console.WriteLine(IsZero(n, 0f)); // true
 Console.WriteLine(IsZero(n, "0")); // compiler error
```

or, with extension method:

```
 Console.WriteLine(n.IsZero(5));  // false
 Console.WriteLine(n.IsZero(0f)); // true
 Console.WriteLine(n.IsZero("0")); // compiler error
```

Comment: 1) Obsolete because Microsoft has released new feature. .NET 7 features the INumber<T> interface. 2) Your example of IsZero method scares me when you do Equality.  How do you properly handle floats and doubles?

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is: Numeric types are value types, hence they derive from System.ValueType. 
The full answer is: you should read this [article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Moreover I think that you should read C# language reference :). Value type not equals numeric type, because values types include also structures and enumerations.

Comment: The article from MSDN does not really consider what is the best type to use when you want a parameter to catch all kinds of number and nothing else - which is what i was asking.

Comment: Yes, but the article shows that decimal type and other floating-point types are different kind of types.

Answer (score 8):

In .NET 7 a new API for [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) was finally introduced.

> .NET 7 introduces new math-related generic interfaces to the base class library. The availability of these interfaces means you can constrain a type parameter of a generic type or method to be "number-like".

It features the [`INumber<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0) interface that is now implemented by all numeric types, so you can do this:

```
public static string FormatDollars<T>(T num) where T : INumber<T>
{
    return "$" + num;
}
```

It also provides [fine-grained numeric interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math#numeric-interfaces) to identify type categories, e.g.:

- `IBinaryInteger<T>` for `Byte` (`byte`), `Int16` (`short`), `Int32` (`int`), `Int64` (`long`), ...
- `IFloatingPoint<T>` for `Double` (`double`), `decimal` (`Decimal`), ...
- ...

For operators it offers a variety of [operator interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math#operator-interfaces)  that are implemented by all numeric types.

- `IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>` for plus (`+`).
- `IMultiplyOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>` for multiply (`*`).
- ...

---

I assume that your question was not explicitly about *value types* but numeric types. However, if you need generic type constraints that enforce value types as well, specify both.

```
public static string FormatDollars<T>(T num) where T : struct, INumber<T>
{
   return "$" + num;
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising!

Answer (score 7):

The base class of the numeric types is [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx).

Unfortunately that still won't help you: `DateTime`, `bool`, `Enum` and hundreds of other types also derive from `ValueType`. There's no `NumericType` base class in .NET.

Comment: Value types aren't necessarily numbers though, are they?

Comment: ValueType also includes strings and other non-numeric value types, however.

Comment: @Noldorin, You're right that ValueType includes hundreds of non-numeric types, however string isn't one of them. String is a reference type (it just behaves a little bit like a value type).

Comment: Also i can't use ValueType as a parameter declaration and then call it with a number, it says it can't find the best match overload.

Comment: @mike, I'm not sure what you mean - I can declare a method "public void Foo(ValueType val)" and pass numbers to it, although I can't really do anything useful with them inside the method.

Comment: @Luke: Yeah, not sure why I said string! String is an immutable reference type, although it indeed appears like a value type.

Comment: @Luke - yes you are right, sorry i got that wrong, thanks for pointing that out. I have now gathered that in fact Double and Decimal cover almost all cases, so i only need two overloads and not squillions as i had first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Are overloaded method signitures out of the question here?
If you want a constrained group of methods to performe the same task you could voerload the public method and call a private method that takes any number via casting the input to a double.

Comment: Formally, that would be a conversion not a cast.

Comment: Well its not impossible, just annoying! Since there are a lot of numeric types. This seems to be the best solution but I was wondering if there was a better way.