# How do I properly write Math extension methods for int, double, float, etc.?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I want to write a series of Extension methods to simplify math operations. For example:

Instead of

```
Math.Pow(2, 5)
```

I'd like to be able to write

```
2.Power(5)
```

which is (in my mind) clearer.

The problem is: how do I deal with the different numeric types when writing Extension Methods? Do I need to write an Extension Method for each type:

```
public static double Power(this double number, double power) {
    return Math.Pow(number, power);
}
public static double Power(this int number, double power) {
    return Math.Pow(number, power);
}
public static double Power(this float number, double power) {
    return Math.Pow(number, power);
}
```

Or is there a trick to allow a single Extension Method work for any numeric type?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Yeah, I'm surprised that wasn't part of the framework to begin with.

Comment: **Caveat** when using such extension methods: **`-10.Power(2) == -100`**. The minus sign get applied to the result of `10.Power(2)`.

Comment: @HugoRune: Interesting point! But I do think that the OP would still be using variables rather than explicit values. The hardcoded values in the question seem to be a matter of example rather than intended usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you are stuck with the three implementations. The only way to get multiple typed methods out of a single definition is using generics, but it is not possible to write a generic method that can do something useful specifically for numeric types.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to override Decimal and Double as is noted in this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828807/what-is-the-base-class-for-c-numeric-value-types)

Answer (score 1):

One solution I use is to make the extension on object. This makes this possible, but unfortunately it will be visible on all objects.

```
public static double Power(this object number, double power) 
{
    return Math.Pow((double) number, power);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible with C# 3.0. Looks like you might be able to do it C# 4.0

http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/02/05/simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0.aspx

Comment: Good point... I'm not sure that the performance hit is going to be worth the price in the general case though.

Comment: the linked artikle does not use dynamic as it was designed, trading type safety for comfort is not the right way i think