# How to get an extension method to appear in a Struct

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, extension-methods

I've created a simple math-related extension method, and would like to add it as a definition to the `UnityEngine.Mathf` struct, simply so I can call it from the same type as I would other math functions. Is this possible?

My method:

```
public static int ZeroIfLess(this Mathf math, int num)
{
    if(num < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return num;
    }
}
```

I also tried adding it as an extension method to `System.Math`, but that didn't work either, due to it being `static`.

Ideally, I'd like it in `UnityEngine.Mathf`, but `System.Math` would also be appropriate.

Comment: As you do not use your `math` parameter, there is no need for an extension method. This looks for me as a normal static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't extend static classes (unless they are marked as `partial`), you need to create your own

or just extend `int` itself

```
public static int ZeroIfLess(this int num)
{
    if(num < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return num;
    }
}
```

or just use a one-liner in-place instead:

```
Math.Max(num, 0)
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realised after seeing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961038/how-do-i-properly-write-math-extension-methods-for-int-double-float-etc?rq=1) in the "related" sidebar that I could extend the `int` itself, which would be suitable too. Using some info from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2009/02/05/simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0.aspx) I'm going to experiment in making a method that incorporates all would-be 'INumerics'. The `Math.Max` function is something I never would have thought of either. :P

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are declared as *static*, but *look like* instance methods. Thus, you cannot use this mechanism to add something that *looks like* a static method.

Your example would require an instance of `Mathf` (or `Math`) to be passed, which is not possible with classes that cannot be instantiated.

I'm afraid what you want is not possible in C#.